# Google Calendar Api view attendees event

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

How to insert **attendees** in get function event of **google calendar api**? Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to use [insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) function, add the property `attendees[].email` in the request body which is the attendee's email address. This field must be present when adding an attendee. Otherwise, if you want to use [get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) function, you can use the parameter `maxAttendees` to show the number of attendees to include in the response.